# Texture stretched, polka dots

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

do you know why my texture is stretched? It's a polka dot motif in a png generated on Photoshop, they are perfect circles but in the model appears as ellipses.
This is Blender 2.90

[image]

Comment: Probably, because your UV is stretched-- too short or too wide for the face.  Edit your UV.

Comment: If your object is scaled, the texture will have scaled with it.

Comment: Apply scale first. It would help if you showed the UV map.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the commenters, but I will go ahead and further explain what goes on here.

A UV map is instructions for how to take an image, and wrap it onto a mesh like wrapping paper. The problem you are having is probably because one of these: UV maps (quite justifiably) do not care about

1. Different aspect ratios of the image than that expected.
2. Changes in the scale of the mesh (this is a *very* good thing, but is likely the trouble you are having).

What is the scale of your object?
How did you make your UV map?
Did you scale the mesh within edit mode after you had UV unwrapped it?

> ... Find out next time on The Happy Family!